# Set color of spinners' background (Share spinner)

Tags: android, colors, background, android-actionbar, spinner

How can I change a color of this standart spinner?:
[image: Problem]

Because white on white is not cool:(( Thx.

Answer (score 1):

It maybe useful for change spinner color:

```
mdt_spn=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.xmdtm_spn);
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter1 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
        getApplicationContext(),android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,mdt_arr) {

    public View getView(int position, View convertView,
            ViewGroup parent) {
        View v = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);

        ((TextView) v).setTextSize(30);
        ((TextView) v).setTextColor(getResources().getColorStateList(R.color.mycolor1));
        return v;
    }

    public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView,
            ViewGroup parent) {
        View v = super.getDropDownView(position, convertView,
                parent);

        ((TextView) v).setTextSize(35);
        ((TextView) v).setTextColor(getResources().getColorStateList(
                R.color.mycolor));


        return v;
    }
};

mdt_spn.setAdapter(adapter1);
```

Comment: It's not my R.id.xmdtm_spn spinner, it's standart autocreated spinner, problem in that!

Answer (score 0):

You should add:

```
android:background="@drawable/myspinner_background"
```

Comment: add it to your `Spinner` attributes and create appropriate drawable

Comment: @ Kostia : You can edit your own answer. In this case, copy comment content to answer, please